# Superset | Dynamically show/hide charts based on data

Tags: analytics, apache-superset

We have a set of data that should populate charts.  The charts should only be displayed if the "visible" field in the dataset for that chart is "true".

Example, the Admin can create a form to ask Users questions.  On that form they can select between 15 questions to ask users.  We have a chart on the dashboard for each question to show results for all the users who have answered.  If the Admin did not select that question, the chart should *not* be visible on the dashboard, showing only the "visible"/selected questions.

Question response data. The first two records are questions that were not selected so don't have any responses. The charts for questions 1 and 2 should *not* be visible on the dashboard.

| QuestionId | QuestionVisible | UserId | Response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | False | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | False | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | True | 123 | 5-Very Satisfied |
| 3 | True | 456 | 1-Not Satisfied |
| 4 | True | 123 | Had a lot of fun |

Can only show/hide via the dashboard CSS, would like to do so based on data.